# Connection between quadratic characters and quadratic twists of elliptic curves

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

So apparently there is some kind of a connection between quadratic characters and twists of elliptic curves that I can't understand.

I am well aware of quadratic twisting of an elliptic curve $E$, we get a curve $E^d$, and the curves are isomorphic over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$.

I also know about quadratic characters associated to fields $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$, given by
$$\chi=\chi_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})}:\mathbb{Z}_{>0} \rightarrow \mathbb{C},$$
$$ \chi(n)=\left( \frac{disc(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}))}{n} \right). $$

In literature I often see twists of elliptic curves $E^d$ being denoted by $E^{\chi}$. Why is that so? what is the connection? Am I even using the right character here?

Comment: In general, there is a bijection between general twists of $E_{/F}$ and elements of $H^1(F, \mathrm{Aut}(E))$ (this is explained in Silverman). In the generic case that $\mathrm{Aut}(E) = \{\pm 1\}$, this $H^1$ is just $\mathrm{Hom}(G_F, \{\pm1\})$ which is in natural bijection with quadratic characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to intemperate this question. As @Mathmo123 says in their comment there is a natural bijection between quadratic characters and twists of $E$ (when the $j$-invariant is not $0$ or $1728$).

From a more elementary point of view we can define a quadratic twist of $E : y^2 = f(x)$ by $E^d : dy^2 = f(x)$. Notice that this is determined by $d$ up to squares - hence is determined by the quadratic extension $F = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}) / \mathbb{Q}$. We obtain a quadratic character
$$ \chi : G_{\mathbb{Q}} \to \langle \pm 1 \rangle$$
of the absolute galois group $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$ by restricting $\sigma \in G_{\mathbb{Q}}$ to $F$ (note that $\operatorname{Gal}(F/\mathbb{Q}) \cong C_2$) (conversely we obtain a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ as the fixed field of the kernel of such a character). Thus there is a bijective correspondence between quadratic twist of $E$ and quadratic characters of the absolute galois group.

A useful application of this thinking is the following

**Lemma** We have
$$E^d(\mathbb{Q}) = \{P \in E : \sigma(P) = \chi(\sigma)P \}$$

*Proof*: Notice that we have $P \in E^d(\mathbb{Q})$ if and only if $P = (x', \sqrt{d}y')$, where $P' = (x', y') \in E(\mathbb{Q})$. Thus $\sigma(P) = P$ if $\sigma$ fixes $F$, or $\sigma(P) = -P$ otherwise, which is precisely the statement.

Comment: Could you please explain how would modular forms associated with twists are related?

Comment: @SUNILPASUPULATI If one takes an elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{Q}$ then there is a related modular form $f(q,E) = \sum a_n q^n$ whose twist by $\chi$ has Fourier coefficients $\chi(n)a_n$, then $f(q, E) \otimes \chi = f(q, E^\chi)$. If you want to know more I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: Does this hold for Tate-Shafarevich group ?  Is $Sha(E_D/\Bbb{Q})=\{P\in Sha(E/K)\mid \sigma(P)=\chi(\sigma)P\}$ where $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ and $\sigma$ is a generator of $Gal(K/\Bbb{Q})$ ? . It seems hold, but I cannot relate elements of $Sha(E_D/\Bbb{Q})$ with elements of $Sha(E/\Bbb{Q})$, so can't imitate the proof of the lemma.