# Rank of elliptic curve over $\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$

Tags: curves, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Rank of elliptic curve over quadratic extension $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ is calculated by a formula $rank(E/K)=rank(E/\Bbb{Q})+rank(E_D/\Bbb{Q})$(this is easy to prove).

Thus rank over quadratic field can be calculated by the information of the rank over $\Bbb{Q}$.

But what is known about the rank over $\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$ ?
For example, can we calculate a rank of $E:y^2=x^3+x$ over
$\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll address the question of generalising the formula $\mathrm{rank}(E/K) = \mathrm{rank}(E/\mathbb Q) + \mathrm{rank}(E_D/\mathbb Q)$.

In general, if $E/K$ is an elliptic curve, then there is an abelian variety
$$A := \mathrm{Res}_{K/\mathbb Q}(E)$$
called the *restriction of scalars of $E$* with the property that
$$A(\mathbb Q) \cong E(K).$$

If $K/\mathbb Q$ is quadratic, then there is an isogeny $A\simeq E \times E_D$ and, since the rank is an isogeny invariant, you recover your formula.

If $K = \mathbb Q(2^{1/ 3})$, then $A$ is isogenous to $E\times B_2$, where $B_2$ is an abelian surface over $\mathbb Q$ that can be described as follows. Let $B = \mathbb Z[\zeta_3]\otimes_{\mathbb Z} E$, an abelian surface over $\mathbb Q$  with $\mathrm{Aut}_{\overline{\mathbb Q}}(B) \supset \langle \zeta_3\rangle$. In particular, $B$ admits cubic twists, and $B_2$ is the cubic twist corresponding to the extension $\mathbb Q(2^{1/ 3})$.

A lot of this and more can be deduced from [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869307001779?via%3Dihub) of Mazur–Rubin–Silverberg.

Comment: Restriction of scalars argument was new to me; it is very elegant. I recently encountered a formula: $Sha(E/K)[p]=Sha(E/\Bbb{Q})[p]+Sha(E_D/\Bbb{Q})[p]$, where $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ ($p\neq 2$ is a prime). I attempted to prove this using the trace map $tr: Sha(E/K) \to Sha(E/\mathbb{Q})$, defined as $[C] \to [C] + [C]^{\sigma}$ ($\sigma$ being the generator of $Gal(K/\Bbb{Q})$). Can this also be explained as a special case of the restriction of scalars argument? (The challenge lies in the fact that $Sha(E/K)[p]$ is not isogeny invariant).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add $#$ to the formula.

Comment: The usual argument is that $\mathrm{Sha}(E/K)[p]$ is a $\mathbb F_p[\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q)]$ module, so it decomposes as two subspaces $V^+$ and $V^-$ on which Galois acts by the trivial character and by the non-trivial quadratic character. You then use the definition of the quadratic twist to identify $V^-$ with $\mathrm{Sha}(E_D/\mathbb Q)[p]$.

Comment: I can't remember if the isogeny $A\simeq E\times E_D$ is actually an isomorphism or not, but even if it's an isogeny, its kernel is certainly a $2$-group. So you would still be able to deduce such a formula, since $p\ne 2$.

Comment: Thank you very much. If my understanding is right, $V_{-1}$ is elements $v$ of $V$ such that $\sigma(v)=-v$ under Galois action . So $V_{-1}=\{[C]\in Sha(E/K)[p] \mid [C/K]+[C/K]^{\sigma}=0 \}$. I'm sticking with the proof this is isomorphic to $Sha(E_D/\Bbb{Q})[p]$ as well as the proof of kernel of trace argument.

Comment: It seems that $V_{-1}\cong \text{Sha}(E_D/K)[p]$ is very nontrivial for me. Does this isomorphism follow from the definition of a quadratic twist?

Comment: Your definition isn't what I had in mind. $V^-$ should be the subspace of elements such that $\sigma(v) = \chi(\sigma) v$, where $\chi$ is the non-trivial quadratic character of $G_{\mathbb Q}$ that factors through $G_K$.

Comment: I'm having difficulty with identifying $V^{-1}$ with $Sha(E_D/\Bbb{Q})[p]$ because I cannot relate the elements of $Sha(E_D/K)$ to the elements of $Sha(E/K)$ as I can with rational points. Could you provide me with a hint? Specifically, what is the mapping between $V^{-1}$ and $Sha(E_D/\Bbb{Q})[p]$? I am struggling to visualize where $[C/K]$ is mapped under this isomorphism.

Comment: Unlike this one,https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3939888/connection-between-quadratic-characters-and-quadratic-twists-of-elliptic-curves, I think we have difficulty identifying $V^{-}$ and $Sha(E_D/K)[p]$ because we cannot write down elements of $Sha(E_D/K)$ using elements of $Sha(E/K)$.

Comment: Also, I think your definition of $V^{-1}$ and mine is the same definition. This is because $G_{\Bbb{Q}}$ acts on $Sha(E/K)$ by $Gal(K/\Bbb{Q})$ action on $sha(E/K)$(This action is defined as action on coefficients of torsos of $E/K$).